# Switch between Fade in and Fade out on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, fadein, fadeout

I want to use jQuery to fade in a div when an image is clicked, when the image is clicked again, I want it to hide and so on.

How would I do this?

I basically need a toggle switch.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#my_img_selector').click(function(){$('#my_div_selector').fadeToggle()});
```

[Try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/vovkss/3muYh/).

Try also `slideToggle()` and `toggle()` in place of `fadeToggle()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the selectors `$('#fadeMe')` and  `$('#bindImage')` according to your markup. The magic is [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/C87GP/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bindImage').on('click', function(){
        $('#fadeMe').fadeToggle();
        //return false; // only useful if you trigger an <a href="#"></a>
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#yourimage').on('click', function(event){
 if ($("#something").is(':visible')) {
 $(".something").hide("drop", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 2000);
}else{
  $(".something").show("drop", {
    direction: "up"
  }, 2000);
}
});
```

Comment: btw this drop if from jquery UI